# MATLAB: Pass part of structure field name to function

Tags: matlab, function, struct

I need to pass a part of a structure's name into a function.

Examples of a available structs:

```
systems.system1.stats.equityCurve.relative.exFee
systems.system1.stats.equityCurve.relative.inFee
systems.system2.stats.equityCurve.relative.exFee
systems.system2.stats.equityCurve.relative.inFee
systems.system1.returns.aggregated.exFee
systems.system1.returns.aggregated.inFee
systems.system2.returns.aggregated.exFee
systems.system2.returns.aggregated.inFee
... This goes on...
```

Within a function, I loop through the structure as follows:

```
function mat = test(fNames)

feeString = {'exFee', 'inFee'};
sysNames = {'system1', 'system2'};

for n = 1 : 2
    mat{n} = systems.(sysNames{n}).stats.equityCurve.relative.(feeString{n});
end

end
```

What I like to handle in a flexible way within the loop is the middle part, i.e. the part after `systems.(sysNames{n})` and before `.(feeString{n})` (compare examples).

I am now looking for a way to pass the middle part as an input argument `fNames` into the function. The loop should than contain something like

```
mat{n} = systems.(sysNames{n}).(fName).(feeString{n});
```

Comment: Dealing with dynamic field names can be quite troublesome, especially if you do not have a fixed number of fields, so my only suggestion (though it is quite chunky) is to use something like: eval(['mat{n} = systems.(sysNames{n}).',fNames,'.(feeString{n});'])

Comment: @DanielAldrich please don't. That's the exact opposite of what sane data handling is. `eval` is slow and unsafe, and it makes code unreadable. Dynamic field names are good and useful, and semantically correct. Please don't try to convince innocent users of the opposite. We're working hard in the [tag:matlab] tag to keep askers off the `eval` path of doom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using a helper function such as

```
function rec_stru = recSA(stru, field_names)
if numel(field_names) == 1
    rec_stru = stru.(field_names{1});
else
    rec_stru = recSA(stru.(field_names{1}), field_names(2:end));
end
```

This function takes the intermediate field names as a cell array.
This would turn this statement:

```
mat{n} = systems.(sysNames{n}).stats.equityCurve.relative.(feeString{n});
```

into

```
mat{n} = recSA(systems.(sysNames{n}), {'stats', 'equityCurve', 'relative', feeString{n}});
```

The first part of the cell array could then be passed as an argument to the function.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of those cases where matlab is a bit unhelpful in the documentation. There is a way to use the `fieldnames` function in matlab to get the list of all the fields and iterate over that using dynamic fields.

```
systems.system1.stats.equityCurve.relative.exFee='T'
systems.system1.stats.equityCurve.relative.inFee='E'
systems.system2.stats.equityCurve.relative.exFee='S'
systems.system2.stats.equityCurve.relative.inFee='T'
systems.system1.returns.aggregated.exFee='D'
systems.system1.returns.aggregated.inFee='A'
systems.system2.returns.aggregated.exFee='T'
systems.system2.returns.aggregated.inFee='A'


dynamicvariable=fieldnames(systems.system1)
```

This will return a cell matrix of the field names which you can use to iterate over.

```
systems.system1.(dynamicvariable{1})

ans = 

equityCurve: [1x1 struct]
```

Ideally you would have your data structure fixed in such a way that you know how many levels of depth are in your data structure.

Comment: But OP seems to know the field names, they just need to access them (recursively) dynamically?

Comment: I know the possible fieldnames with one exception: I don't know the number of the second level, i.e. there are N systems (system1, system2,...,systemN). There are a couple of "middle parts" (known) and always two end parts (.exFee and .inFee).

Comment: probably use `isstruct` in your function to keep droping 1 level down your nested data structure until you get to the fees

Comment: @Andi Recommendation is the same as what @zeeMonkeez posted, write a helper function with `isstruct` rather than `numel(field_names)` which will maintain a bit more flexibility on when you hit the last level of your nested structure.